# CC Payment error, Sagepay form integration with Magento 1.9

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, magento-1.9, opayo

Sagepay form integration with Magento. I'm on test mode now, and everytime I make a purchase using Sagepay test mode. I get this message:

> The payment was made with success however an error occurred, your credit card has been charged. Please contact our support team.

It occurs when redirected back to my website from Sagepay payment gateway.

I've contacted Sagepay and they don't know how to solve this issue. The orders are created on magento backend but they are not authenticated since an error occurred. So I cannot invoice it or anything like that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is not enough information here for someone to diagnose. Recommend you add more information, your code, any php errors etc.

Comment: Thanks for the grammer! Do you have like English course materials ? Or could you help me improve me english ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this site - http://ell.stackexchange.com. This site is similar to Stack Overflow, but focused on questions about learning english. I am not a teacher though. Actually your English is reasonably good, I just improved your post.